# Should Storm Spouts only emit output using the thread calling Spout.nextTuple?

Tags: multithreading, apache-storm

The [`ISpout.nextTuple()` javadoc](http://storm.incubator.apache.org/apidocs/backtype/storm/spout/ISpout.html#nextTuple%28%29) specifies that `nextTuple()`, `ack(...)` and `fail(...)` are called on the same thread.

However, the actual collector upon which `emit(...)` is called is supplied earlier, as a parameter on `open(..., collector)`.

Question is whether a background thread that sees some new data must always enqueue the data for nextTuple() to dequeue and emit. What would happen if the background thread emits the data immediately? Is that supported? If that is allowed, what's the recommended way to implement the "sleep for a short amount of time" in `nextTuple()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implicit meaning of `nextTuple()/ack()/fail()` methods are called on the same thread is, the task (background Java thread), running at machine 'A', which emits the tuple is the same task, running at 'A' on which the ack()/fail() is called depending on the success/failure of processing (processed by Bolt running at 'B'or 'C') the tuple in the topology.

As long as the messageId is not null and Bolt tasks are calling the ack(tuple) in the execute() method, Storm framework keeps track of tuple traversal within the topology and call the ack()/fail() of tuple's owning task.

Here is the brief introduction on how the background task thread works before answering your question. The background task thread has in-memory structure/buffer for the emitted tuple and few other in-memory structures for status/pending tuples etc. The buffer gets filling up as the Spout/Bolt starts emitting the data and this buffer getting freed up as and when the tuples are processed i.e after calling ack()/fail(). Essentially, the background thread calls `nextTuple()` when the buffer is free and background thread stops calling the `nextTuple()` once the buffer is full. In simple words, emit() method either in the `open()/nextTuple()/close()`, fills the background thread buffer and `ack()/fail()` frees up the buffer.

With the above explanation, the background thread is unaware of the new/incoming data. It's up to the logic within the nextTuple() to read the data from source(Twitter/JMS providers/ESB/AMQP compliant servers/RDBMS) and emit the data. So, depending on the background thread's buffer size, Storm calls nextTuple() as explained above.

For other question, it should be ok to sleep for short duration if it's required. Please note, the `nextTuple()` need not emit the value, it can return with nothing.

Comment: Great answer. Would you please add a reference to some design document, or point out an important piece of code that supports this explanation? I ask simply because there's no reason the underlying infrastructure *couldn't* keep track of data emitted through the collector, and either have a unbound buffer or block on `emit(...)` calls.

Comment: The 'nextTuple()' method is called by executor.clj, Please see the source code at line 462 at [executor.clj](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/blob/moved-to-apache/storm-core/src/clj/backtype/storm/daemon/executor.clj). Comments are mentioned at line 456 on the same source

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that you shouldn't emit data unless requested by Storm by calling your nextTuple() method. Consequently, your background thread must enqueue new data, so that it is emitted when requested. Your nextTuple() method should sleep briefly only if there are no tuples to emit when the method is called.

Comment: thanks. This is my intuition as well, but I've not found anything stating this explicitly. Would you have a reference to cite? In the meantime, I am proceeding with work assuming this limitation.

Comment: Good question. Based on my readings, I was fairly sure about emiting data only through nextTuple(). However, while looking for an explicit statement I noticed the following text in the description of the _collector_ parameter from ISpout.open(): _"Tuples can be emitted at any time, including the open and close methods"_. So I think you should give a try to emitting as soon as the data arrives. If that was the case, could you please report the results of such testing here? Thanks in advance!